# Como ignorar arquivos de acordo com a sua extensão no TFS?

Tags: c#, versionamento, team-foundation-server

No git é possível utilizar o arquivo .gitignore para ignorar algumas extensões de arquivos, mas gostaria de saber se isso também pode ser feito no Team Foundation Service ou se existe algo semelhante para ignorar arquivos com determinadas extensões.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No workspace local você tera o arquivo .tfignore (TFS 2012, 2013, 2015 e superior)

No workspace local, você pode usar o .tfignore (que é equivalente ao .gitignore do Git)

.tfignore exemplo:

```
######################################
# Ignore .cpp files in the ProjA sub-folder and all its subfolders
ProjA\*.cpp
# 
# Ignore .txt files in this folder 
\*.txt
#
# Ignore .xml files in this folder and all its sub-folders
*.xml
#
# Ignore all files in the Temp sub-folder
\Temp
#
# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll
```

Lembrando que o .tfignore é valido para novos arquivos.

Comment: Eu já tenho um projeto no controle de versão, por isso criei o arquivo .tfignore com as extensões a serem excluídas e dei check-in, porém os arquivos com as respectivas extensões continuam na lista de included changes.

Comment: e na lista de changes se der um botao da direita ignore funciona para você?

Comment: qualquer coisa da uma olhada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768954/visual-studio-2015-tfs-tfignore-file pode ser o formato do arquivo que nao esta correto

Comment: Bom, o que acontece é que o .tfignore só é válido para os arquivos que ainda não estão no controle de versão, por isso eu não estava conseguindo. Obrigado pelo link, ajudou muito !

Comment: @Carlinhos adicionei o comentario na resposta, se te ajudou marque como resolvido.